# Ubuntu 14.04 - White noise when playing mixcloud/youtube in Firefox (ARM)

Tags: firefox, arm

Mixcloud/Youtube plays perfectly in Chromium but in Firefox 50.1.0 all I hear is white noise (but I can see the videos).
My computer uses the Tegra K1 processor so is ARM architecture.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox` fixed this.